# Electron cant connect to imap server

Tags: electron, connection, imap

When I try to connect to an imap server in electron like `mail.someone.com 143`, I get the following error:

> Error: getaddrinfo enotfound mail.somone.com, getaddrinforequestwrap...

What am I missing? Is it because it's trying to connect to kinda localhost?

```
  createServer() {
    return net.createConnection({
      port: '143',
      host: 'mail.somone.com'
    })
  }
```

The code is working perfectly fine in pure nodejs without electron, so I'm thinking maybe electron does something with localhost behind the scenes?

Comment: Is it trying to connect to local host or is it trying to connect to mail.someone.com?